# iphone crash log with dSym not loading debug information

Tags: iphone, crash, logging, adhoc

I was trying to see why my application crashed on the device (iPhone) using the dSym generated along the executable (in ad hoc), but I don't know why, there isn't any useful information. It seems that "Organizer" is able to find the appropriate dSym and translate some data into more readable one, but when it comes to my application, I just have an address.

Since I know how to reproduce it, I've tried to setup my build so it can help me in the future. So, I've tried to find if I had all the proper flags set int the project build properties and everything seems fine. So after doing some research, it seems that all information are stripped during link time and the dSym seems completely useless. I've played with some flags, but nothing changed.

So, is there something special to do in order to get the crash file human readable? Or is it impossible in the ad hoc setting? The closest thing near to work that I've done was to build a debug version and look up the address in it. At least it seems to give the right  file. So, I made a sample app and here what I have: (the line I want is #4):

```
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libobjc.A.dylib                0x00003ebc objc_msgSend + 20
1   UIKit                          0x0005c970 -[UIView dealloc] + 60
2   UIKit                          0x0005c840 -[UIImageView dealloc] + 76
3   CoreFoundation                 0x0003963a -[NSObject release] + 28
4   MyApplication                  0x000046a6 0x1000 + 13990
5   UIKit                          0x00069750 -[UIViewController view] + 44
6   MyApplication                  0x000053fa 0x1000 + 17402
```

The crash is made using 2 successive releases on an object.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After many infructuous retries in order to get the debug information, I decided to create a new project from scratch and re-add everything into it. And now it works fine. So it was probably some kind of hidden settings somewhere that was making it behave like that. I don't know what it was and I'm still curious about it.

Answer (score 1):

I have found this helpful:

http://www.anoshkin.net/blog/2008/09/09/iphone-crash-logs/

Comment: I've already come across this web page and I've downloaded symbolicatecrash since it wasn't with my SDK and didn't do much. It doesn't add anything that Organizer does't already do.